# conditional or js to detect whether user is on windows XP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Because windows xp renders certain fonts so poorly, i would like to detect whether the user is using that OS and add a class to the body accordingly.

**I'm looking ideally for an html conditional statement or php $_SERVER var to do this**

However failing that a piece of javscript along the lines of below would do

```
if(users_os === 'xp'){
    $('body').addClass('xp');
}
```

What avenues should i be persuing?!!!

thanks!

---

EDIT: TO CLARIFY!

This is further development on a project which renders the webapp in nicer fonts if the user has it natively installed - see part of my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715434/ingenious-idea-needed-how-to-declare-different-sizes-for-different-fonts-font/2715544#2715544): for extending font stacks abilities.

Fonts render differently on combinations of OS and Browser, not Browser alone - i want to be able to know whether a user is on xp or not becuase it's rendering of Calibri is so very poor

Comment: What exactly do you mean "renders fonts so poorly"? Do you mean ClearType or the absence of it?

Comment: I agree that Windows' font rendering can be quite terrible, especially for Asian scripts. But, IMHO, **so be it**. Windows users are used to it. As longs as it's legible, they probably won't care. Use one of the Flash or image substitution solutions if you really care about pixel perfect text rendering cross-browser.

Comment: hi pekka, i've updated my question to clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fully agree with [jAndy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067916/conditional-or-js-to-detect-whether-user-is-on-windows-xp/3067935#3067935), you shouldn't ever need OS detection for a web application and you should rarely need browser detection (the exception being stats/analytics, of course).

That being said, if you're insistent you need this, you can get what you need to know using the PHP function [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php):

```
$browser = get_browser();
echo $browser["platform"];
// -> "WinXP"
```

Comment: this looks great Andy, the only reason i'm doing this is to beautify my app without sacrificing performance. (text replacement services like cufon and remotely hosted fonts like typekit/webfonts have slight performance problems)

Comment: @Haroldo: I understand and fully encourage you to do as you please.  When people talk about how it's a bad idea to use browser detection, they do so in the knowledge that it is unreliable vs feature detection.  For instance, checking for IE6 to use ActiveX instead of native `XMLHttpRequest` is a bad idea because it can be disabled in IE7/8.  What your doing doesn't seem like it could do any harm, so I don't think anyone can present a *real* argument against it

Answer (score 7):

It actually makes **no sense** to determine which `operating system` is used for a **Web** Application. The only thing which should be of interest, is the `Browser`. Even in the Browser you just have to care about what it supports and what not.

In JQuery you may use the [.support()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/), [.browser()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) and [.boxModel()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.boxModel/) methods for that purpose.

Comment: Also, given Cleartype 8can8 be enabled on Windows XP, the original check fails (also differing browsers can implement differing rendering routines)

Comment: @Evan: And only allow what to view the page?

Comment: i disagree, the operating system makes a big difference to font rendering, have you tried it?

Comment: @Haroldo I just tried a `span` with Calibri in both Windows 7 and its built-in Windows XP virtual machine (on which I haven't changed any settings). They look identical to me in Firefox: http://pekkagaiser.com/blog/user/files/Calibri.PNG I had to install Calibri as it doesn't ship with XP by default - but that's a different issue, and you're going to have that on Macs, Linux-based machines etc. as well. Can you show an example of how fonts are rendered differently?

Comment: @Haroldo: I'm not saying there is no difference I'm just saying it makes no sense to check for that. Looking at Windows alone has how many, 4,5, 6 different `OS` versions? In that different OS versions you have to care about 3-5 different browser behaviors on that platform? It should not within your scope to care about the OS. You still can do, but its senseless as before

Comment: @pekka, thanks pekka i rechecked on my XP machine. I've been a massive bellend and realised that the browser was zoomed out 1 notch. Zoomed to 100% it looks ok and not awful! definately worse than xp and vista, but certainly fine and not worth making special exceptions for. thanks for your help(s)!

Comment: @jAndy, I would say that if the display was as bad as i thought it was (and didnt have it on wrong zoom) it would have definitely been worth making a special case for XP. I'm not concerned about aesthetics pre-xp and post xp microsoft seem to have sorting things out!

Comment: just one thing where font rendering depends on OS: On windows XP, fonts are aliased in elements rotated with css `transform: rotate(Xdeg)` (e.g. `div` with text). You can read them, but they look really really bad. And this is a OS-level-issue (windows XP) - at least it looks bad in the browsers firefox, IE, safari/chrome I tested. Win7: no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with PHP you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. This string contains the browser, but also the OS. Example

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
```

With the "substr" function (which is faster) or an preg_match you can extract the OS from the string.

Comment: i never like to *depend* on string matching (strpos/preg_match) for a futureproof solution, can you see any problems with Andy E's head's solution?

Comment: @Haroldo: the difference is that PHP handles the matching for you, it still uses the HTTP_USER_AGENT string, but it does the heavy lifting so you don't have to.

Comment: @Andy E's head: That's what I wanted to write :)

Answer (score 0):

You should perform a check on navigator.appVersion, which contains OS version (my Win 7 become "Windows NT 6.1"):

Try this on your browser address bar to see which values are returned.

```
javascript:alert(navigator.appVersion);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
function OS()
{
    var n = navigator.oscpu;
    var Name = "empty";

    var osName = new Array("Windows XP", "Windows Vista", "Windows 7");

    var osNameAlt = new Array("Windows NT 5.1", "Windows NT 6.0", "Windows NT 6.1");

    for(a=0;a < osNameAlt.length; a++)
    {
        if (n == osNameAlt[a])
        {
            this.Name = osName[a];

            break;
        }


    }   

}



var os = new OS();


alert(os.Name);
```

Just add the OS names to the array

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment reply to [Adam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067916/conditional-or-js-to-detect-whether-user-is-on-windows-xp/3067931#3067931), *this will **only** work in Firefox!*

Comment: Didn't see the comment until now. And posted this before i knew.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigator.platform` also:

```
var isXP = /NT 5.1/.test(navigator.platform)
```

quirksmode.org has a great class you can use to detect the browser platform [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) (pasted below).

I have used similar methods to conditonally include CSS on Mac platforms, as fonts can be quite different on the Mac and even break layouts with their size and spacing difference. I did it because it was *very late in the project* and we need a band-aid. I'm a fan of just letting different sites look different in different browsers, as long as they remain functional and attractive. For example, I implement rounded corners using CSS only, and therefore they don't show in IE. I think this is acceptable, but some may not (have a look at [quoterobot.com](http://www.quoterobot.com/) for an example - not my work by the way!)

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {   string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "OmniWeb",
            versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
            identity: "OmniWeb"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "iCab",
            identity: "iCab"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "KDE",
            identity: "Konqueror"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Camino",
            identity: "Camino"
        },
        {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Netscape",
            identity: "Netscape"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Explorer",
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Gecko",
            identity: "Mozilla",
            versionSearch: "rv"
        },
        {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Mozilla",
            identity: "Netscape",
            versionSearch: "Mozilla"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: "iPhone",
               identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();
```